# Does sonar analyse code in test directory of a Maven project?

Tags: maven, junit, sonarqube

Does sonar analyse code in test directory of Maven project ?

In the project I'm working on I don't think it does but I'm unsure if this has been turned off or is enabled by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sure not every metrics is applied to tests. sonar counts number of tests (but it's probably from junit's report) but checkstyle etc will not analyse tests - unfortunately. at least not with default settings

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sonar checks unit test files against PMD unit test rules and of course creates violations on test files if any of them(rules) are broken. By default, however, these rules are disabled so you need to enable them in profile administration